# Irreducibility in polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $x^3+a$ is reducible in $\mathbf{Z}_3[x]$ {list of all polynomials with their coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}_3$} and $a \in \mathbf{Z}_3$.

Attempted solution: I just can think of 1 example If $a=2$ and $x=1$, the polynomial is irreducible. Is that enough to show?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can approach this in a case-by-case way of considering $a = 0,1,2$ and show each of $x^3$, $x^3 + 1$, and $x^3 + 2$ has a root in $\mathbf{Z}_3$. Edit: the answer below is better!

Answer (score 4):

How do you mean if $x=1$? $x$ is your variable. You can always reduce it as $$x^3 + a = (x+a)^3,$$ so it is always reducible.

Comment: Aha, $(\pm1)^3=\pm 1$, and $3x^2a=0=3xa^2$

Comment: Freshman's dream....

Comment: @Berci Cubing here is the Frobenius automorphism so it respects addition. We also have $a^3 = a$ by Fermat's little theorem. This will hold for any prime, not just $3$

Comment: Ah! I see it now! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 3\!:\ \{0,\,\pm 1\}^3\! = \{0,\,\pm1\}\:\Rightarrow\: a^3\! \equiv a \:\Rightarrow\: f(-a) \equiv 0\:$